# Trying to download files without starting scrapy project but from .py file. Created Custom pipeline within python file, This error comes as metioned

Tags: scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.pipelines.files import FilesPipeline
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import os

class DatasetItem(scrapy.Item):
    file_urls = scrapy.Field()
    files = scrapy.Field()

class MyFilesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    pass



class DatasetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'Dataset_Scraper'
    url = 'https://kern.humdrum.org/cgi-bin/browse?l=essen/europa/deutschl/allerkbd'
    

    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53       7.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    }
    
    custom_settings = {
            'FILES_STORE': 'Dataset',
            'ITEM_PIPELINES':{"/home/LaxmanMaharjan/dataset/MyFilesPipeline":1}

            }
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(
                url = self.url,
                headers = self.headers,
                callback = self.parse
                )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = DatasetItem()
        links = response.xpath('.//body/center[3]/center/table/tr[1]/td/table/tr/td/a[4]/@href').getall()
        
        for link in links:
            item['file_urls'] = [link]
            yield item
            break
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #run spider from script
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(DatasetSpider)
    process.start()
```

Error : Error loading object home-LaxmanMaharjan-dataset-Pipeline': not a full path

path is correct

How do i use custom file pipeline within this python file??? Help

I am trying to add custom file pipeline to download files with proper name. I cannot mention file pipeline class name cause it requires path so when entered path above error comes.

Comment: Your question could be clearer. I doubt the `ITEM_PIPELINES` path is correct. Anyway, try replacing `"/home/LaxmanMaharjan/dataset/MyFilesPipeline"` with `MyFilesPipeline`

Comment: @tomjn Yes sir i did that but it says MyFilesPipeline is not a path

Comment: Did you do `"MyFilesPipeline"` or `MyFilesPipeline`? The latter should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if pipeline code, spider code and process launcher stored in the same file 
You can use `__main__` in path to enable pipeline:

```
custom_settings = {
        'FILES_STORE': 'Dataset',
        'ITEM_PIPELINES':{"__main__.MyFilesPipeline":1}
        }
```